# Google Geocoder - Add co-ordinates to fields

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode

I am trying to find some minamilistic google geocoding script. The ones I have found are very large and complicated, but this one is very simple. The only thing it doesnt do is actually put the co-ordinates in two input boxes like the others.

Here is the code working:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/89/

How do I get it to put the co-ordinates in a long / lat input field? It must have them stored because it uses them to display on the map.

```
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to put them in input fields? You already have them stored on variables.

Comment: I want to pass them to my URL, ie www.url.com/search?long=123lat=456

Comment: You can simply take them from the Javascript variables. You don't need input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply take them from the Javascript variables. You don't need input fields.

```
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
var url = 'www.url.com/search?lon='+lon+'&lat='+lat;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to put latitude and longitude in text fields you need to create 2 text boxes first and put latitude and longitude.

```
var latitude= results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var longitude=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

This jsfiddle shows an example.
http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/njDvn/6/

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, try this

```
var loc=results[0].geometry.location;
document.getElementById('latLng').value=loc.lat()+', '+loc.lng();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Rr5PL/94/).

Comment: You should **never** use undocumented properties like .cb or .eb; They are minified names and they are likely to change without notice in future releases of the API.